# Write Formula using differential forms

Tags: vector-analysis, differential-forms

let $\alpha, \beta \in C^2(\Omega)$ be zero forms

Where $\Omega$ is a regular surface with boundary $\partial{\Omega}$. I have to write the following formula using differential forms

\begin{equation}
  \int_{\Omega} \nabla\alpha \times \nabla \beta \ \cdot d\Omega = \int_{\partial{\Omega}} \alpha  \nabla \beta \ \cdot dr      
\end{equation}

What I have done so far:

$\nabla \alpha = \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x }\hat{x}+\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y }\hat{y}+\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z }\hat{z}$

$\nabla \beta = \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x }\hat{x}+\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y }\hat{y}+\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial z }\hat{z}$

\begin{equation}
\nabla \alpha \times \nabla \beta = \begin{vmatrix}
 \hat{x} & \hat{y} & \hat{z} \\
 \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x } & \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y } & \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z } \\
\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x } & \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y } & \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial z }
\end{vmatrix} = ( \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial z } \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y } - \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y } \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z } ) \hat{x} -( \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial z } \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x } - \frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial z } \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x } ) \hat{y} + (\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial x }\frac{\partial \beta}{\partial y } - \frac{\partial \beta}{\partial x }\frac{\partial \alpha}{\partial y } )\hat{z} 
\end{equation}

But I'm stuck, I don't know how to continue.  Maybe $d\Omega = (dydz,dzdx,dxdy)$,  $dr = (dx,dy,dz)$ and then I have to compute the dot product but I'm not sure.

Any hint? Thank you.

Comment: Your right-hand side makes no sense, as you can't take the cross product of a scalar and a vector. It should just be $\int_{\partial\Omega}\alpha\nabla\beta\cdot dr$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one step with Stokes's Theorem:
$$\int_\Omega d\alpha\wedge d\beta = \int_{\partial\Omega} \alpha\,d\beta,$$
since $d(\alpha\,d\beta) = d\alpha\wedge d\beta$.
Note that if $\vec F = (F_1,F_2,F_3)$, the flux integral $\displaystyle\int \vec F\cdot d\vec S$ is precisely given by integrating the $2$-form $F_1\,dy\wedge dz + F_2\,dz\wedge dx + F_3\,dx\wedge dy$, as you suggested.